# Fetching text area or text editor's value

Tags: jquery, mysql, html, servlets

I have a text editor I have used "NicEdit" rich text editor. The user types some text and character. How do I fetch the same content and save it in the database. I am using the servlet  at the back end and jquery and html5 at the front end and I am using Mysql database.

I just need to get the data from the rich editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/525/Saving-via-AJAX) while i was watching for the article that i was using last time.

There you find a example how to save with Ajax

**EDIT:**

There seems to be a `saveContents()` function.

i found [this](http://www.netshinesoftware.com/component/option,com_myblog/Itemid,65/show,Capturing-content-from-nicEdit-when-form-is-submitted-by-javascript.html/)(Also watch the comments) example:

```
onclick="nicEditors.findEditor('textarea_id').saveContent();document.myForm.submit();"
```